# SwiftUI, how to disable touches on List item, but enable touches on subviews of the List items?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I saw some solutions, but they require your define specific gestures.
Are there any solution which could accept all gesture and ignore the List item?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is doesn't use it at all because the List is:

> a container that presents rows of data arranged in a single column,
> optionally providing the ability to select one or more members.

Try to use something like

```
ScrolView {
  ForEach(items) { item in
    Row(item)
  }
}
```